# Virtualbox NFS mount kills ethernet on host machine

Tags: 16.04, networking, virtualbox, ethernet, nfs

I am using Ubuntu 16.04.02 LTS 64bit (Unity desktop) with latest 4.4.0.x kernel.
My hardware is generic laptop with folowing specs:

- RAM: 8Gb
- CPU: i5 4200M (Haswell)
- Ethernet: Realtek RTL8168
- WIFI: Realtek RTL8723AE

My daily work consists on using or creating virtual machines for development purposes. I observed that whenever I start VM that mounts directory from the host file system using NFS my ethernet NIC just dies.

[image: Virtualbox]

I just get "Ethernet Network() device not managed"

This never happened on Ubuntu 14.04 that I used before on the same machine.

Any ideas?

Comment: Is your vm using the network card as "bridged" or "host-only adapter"?

Comment: It is using host-only adapter.